# How can I create a data-aware TCheckListBox?

Tags: delphi, pascal

In my software, I'm using a standard `TCheckListBox` making it data-aware in the application code.

It is working. When I want to save, I use this code:

```
for i := 0 to clbGrp.Items.Count-1 do
begin
  if clbGrp.Checked[i] then grp:=grp+'1' else grp:=grp+'0';
end;
```

(`i : smallint;` and `grp: string`)

And when I want to show the form, I use this:

```
var i:smallint;
begin
  for i := 0 to clbGrp.Items.Count-1 do clbGrp.Checked[i]:=False;
     for i := 0 to clbGrp.Items.Count-1 do
      begin
        clbGrp.Checked[i]:=StrToBool(Dm.TblFytFytGrup.AsString[i+1]);
      end;
```

Here is the problem.

I need this task as common and I don't want to do it in code every time, scanning data rows like that.

So I want to create a data-aware version of this component.

How can I achieve this?

I know there exists some commercial component but I want learn to do it by myself.

Comment: You could try digging the VCL code for the examples. For instance, you could take a look at the implementation of `TDBEdit`, since your component is supposed to be linked to a *single column value*, like the edit component (as opposed to linking to a *row set*, like `TDBGrid`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use this component http://www.delphipages.com/records.cfm?kw=tdbchecklistbox or start creating your own component - here is a very good tutorial on how to do it http://www.delphidabbler.com/tips/194

Answer (score 1):

> I know there exists some commercial component but I want learn to do it by myself.

Then take a look at [Is there a data-aware tab control available?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9793255/757830) which deals with a multi-record dataset.

Comment: As you can see in my code, my checklistbox is working only on one field uses the strings bytes for values. but thanks for proposal and ill try to look it and learn the techniques.

Comment: I said multi-record, not multi-field. You must be confused with the several controls shown on the tab-control, which are placed designtime. Only the tab captions are managed by the component, like your ListBox will do for the string items.